# Typescript: Accessing injected function from function delegate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

We're in the process of porting our existing angularjs app to typescript. As this is a work in progress, we use the "any" type pretty heavily (just for clarification).

One of our larger services is being rewritten at the moment, but it heavily uses the `$http` service from Angular and I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

We have a method exposed on a service that wraps a lot of functionality. Here's the basic class (dumbed down version):

```
class MyService implements IMyService {
    static $inject = ["$http", "MyException"];

    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private MyException: any) {
    }

    search(searchType: string, page: number): ng.IPromise<any> {
        var apiCall = // Not important.
        return this.executeApiCall(apiCall, this.onSearchComplete);
    }

    private executeApiCall(apiCall: string, onDataComplete: any): ng.IPromise<any> {
        var request: any = {
            method: "GET",
            url: apiCall
        };

        return this.$http(request).then(onDataComplete);
    }

    private onSearchComplete(response: any): any {
        if(!response.hasOwnProperty(Stuff)) {
            var customError = new MyException(); // CAN'T ACCESS MyException!!
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that since the `onSearchComplete` callback is passed as a delegate, I have no idea how to access `MyException` from it.

The `this` keyword isn't available in the normal sense in that function, which is the normal way I've seen you access class properties in TS.

I've trying using something similar to:

```
return this.executeApiCall(apiCall, this.onSearchComplete.bind(this));
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything, as the compiled JavaScript is no different than having the exact same statement without the `bind`.

My Google-foo is failing me here, and as I'm still new to TypeScript can't figure out how to accomplish the above.

Please let me know if I need to provide more details.

Comment: Can you create a codepen or similar showing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, MyException isn't defined on `onSearchComplete` method scope, it is

```
var customError = new this.MyException();
```

`this.onSearchComplete.bind(this)` may do the work. It is [JS feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and doesn't do anything on compilation time. But the best way to do this is [arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) which is intended especially to introduce lexical `this` inside functions:

```
private onSearchComplete = (response: any): any => {
    if(!response.hasOwnProperty(Stuff)) {
        var customError = new this.MyException();
    }
}
```

And event handler is most obvious use case for it.

Comment: What do you mean by: "And MyException should be assigned as `this` property in constructor as well."? I tried changing to arrow functions and I get the same result. This is undefined.

Comment: Looks like my compiled JS isn't assigning a _this anywhere. I wonder why that would be.

Comment: Turns out the answer was twofold. One, I needed to use the arrow function as above, two my compiler needed to be updated. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, it is a nice sugar syntax for good old 'var self = this'. Notice that for nested functions all of them should be arrows to propagate lexical 'this' there.